# How to draw tikz paths composed only of horizontal, vertical and diagonal segments?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Inspired by a recent question on stackoverflow about how to draw maps of transportation networks, I'm wondering how to draw paths that consists of vertical, horizontal and diagonal segments.

Just like one can use `|-` to compose the path of vertical and horizontal segments, I'd like to have a method to automatically replace all square corners with diagonal lines (it is not important if the diagonal segment is at the start, end or in the middle of the path, all would be fine -- bonus points if the inclination if the diagonal segments remains constant)

For illustration: I'd like to automatically draw the red path in the following image without manually adding the break points

[image]

Points that have a larger vertical than horizontal distance could be connected like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Marmot) at (0,1);
\coordinate (Duck) at (2,0);

\draw (Marmot) -- (Duck);
\draw (Marmot) |- (Duck);

\draw[red] (Marmot) -- (0.5,1) -- (1.5,0) -- (Duck);

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Marmot) {Marmot Burrow};
\draw (Marmot) circle (0.05);

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Duck) {Duck Pond};
\draw (Duck) circle (0.05);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Would you like to have the red path generated automatically just like the black ones?

Comment: @Superuser27 Yes, I'm looking for a way to automatically draw the red path - I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: Should the inclination be a modifiable parameter or do you always want an angle of say 45°?

Comment: @AndréC 45 degree is good enough, but I won't complain if it is adjustable :)

Comment: Do you mean you prefer adjustable angle than 45 degrees.. (because it will be more complicated in math calculations) ? or you would not need other angle and thus the extra calculation would just the code worse for you?

Comment: @koleygr I would be totally satisfied with 45 degree.

Comment: I added an answer with some calculations not too complicated, but had to do extra checks for the `\PrrfectAnglr`s

Comment: @koleygr Perfect! Thanks a lot for your edit!

Comment: Welcome @semcarter...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438293/121799 ?

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the link! That's indeed the same problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I felt like I want to slightly adapt [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438293/121799) to the somewhat more general requirements. This answer comes with a modified `connect with angle` style which can be used like this:

```
\draw[blue] (Marmot) to[connect with angle=-60] (Duck);
```

It does all the cases automatically, and is arguably more Ti*k*Zy than writing a macro. This is also because you can combine such paths as in

```
\draw[orange] (Duck) to[connect with angle=125] (Marmot)
to[connect with angle=115] (Koala);
```

These paths can then define contours of something you want to fill, shade or clip against, or compute intersections with.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks,tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{connect with angle/.style={to path={%
let \p1=(\tikztostart),\p2=(\tikztotarget),\n1={sin(#1-atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1))} in 
\ifdim\n1>0pt
-- ++(0,{((\y2-\y1)-(\x2-\x1)*tan(#1))/2}) 
-- ++({(\x2-\x1)},{(\x2-\x1)*tan(#1)})
-- (\tikztotarget)
\else
-- ++({((\x2-\x1)-(\y2-\y1)*cot(#1))/2},0) 
-- ++({(\y2-\y1)*cot(#1)},{\y2-\y1})
-- (\tikztotarget)
\fi}}}
\newsavebox{\Duck}
\newsavebox{\Koala}
\newsavebox{\Marmot}
\sbox{\Duck}{\tikz{\duck}}
\sbox{\Koala}{\tikz{\koala}}
\sbox{\Marmot}{\tikz{\marmot}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label=below:marmot] (Marmot) at (0,1);
    \coordinate[label=below:duck] (Duck) at (2,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:koala] (Koala) at (-2,3);
    \draw (Marmot) -- (Duck);
    \draw (Marmot) |- (Duck);
    \node[rotate=-10,anchor=south] at (Marmot) {\usebox\Marmot};
    \draw (Marmot) circle (0.05);
    \node[rotate=-45,anchor=south] at (Duck) {\usebox\Duck};
    \draw (Duck) circle (0.05);
    \node[rotate=10,anchor=south] at (Koala) {\usebox\Koala};
    \draw (Koala) circle (0.05);
    \draw[red] (Duck) to[connect with angle=135] (Marmot);
    \draw[blue] (Marmot) to[connect with angle=-60] (Duck);
    \draw[red] (Marmot) to[connect with angle=120] (Koala);
    \draw[blue] (Koala) to[connect with angle=-80] (Marmot);
    \draw[orange,fill=red,fill opacity=0.2] (Duck) to[connect with angle=125] (Marmot)
    to[connect with angle=115] (Koala) |-cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**

With 45 degrees angle (but if their angle is already 45,135,225 or 315 it will give a straight line)

I used the command of @AlanMatthes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20864/120578)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
  \def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
  }


%Command \diagconnect
% #1 is the arguments of \draw command like, red, thick etc
% #2 is the optional argument of the fraction of the horizontal distance for the break according to the horizontal distance of the points
% #3 and #4 are the points to be connected
\newcommand{\diagconnect}[3][-,red,thick]{
\tikzAngleOfLine(#2)(#3){\Angle}
\xdef\PerfectAngle{0}
\foreach \x in {45,135,225,315} {\ifdim\dimexpr \Angle pt\relax=\dimexpr\x pt\relax\xdef\PerfectAngle{1}\fi}
\ifnum\PerfectAngle=0
\ifdim\dimexpr\Angle pt \relax< \dimexpr90 pt\relax\relax
\draw[#1] let\p1=(#2),\p2=(#3) in (#2)-- ($(#2)+({(\x2-\x1)-abs(\x2-\x1)/(\x2-\x1)*abs(\y2-\y1))/2},0)$)--($(#3)-({(\x2-\x1)-abs(\x2-\x1)/(\x2-\x1)*abs(\y2-\y1))/2},0)$)--(#3);
\else 
\draw[#1] let\p1=(#2),\p2=(#3) in (#2)-- ($(#2)+(0,{(\x2-\x1)-abs(\x2-\x1)/(\x2-\x1)*abs(\y2-\y1))/2})$)--($(#3)-(0,{(\x2-\x1)-abs(\x2-\x1)/(\x2-\x1)*abs(\y2-\y1))/2})$)--(#3);
\fi
\else
\draw[#1] (#2)--(#3);
\fi
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point1) at (0,0){Point 1};
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point2) at (1,3) {Point 2};

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point3) at (4,0){Point 3};
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point4) at (7,1) {Point 4};

\diagconnect{Point1}{Point2};

\diagconnect{Point3}{Point4}

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point5) at (0,-4){Point 5};
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point6) at (2,-6) {Point 6};

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point7) at (4,-4){Point 7};
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point8) at (5,-7) {Point 8};

\diagconnect{Point5}{Point6};

\diagconnect{Point7}{Point8}

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point9) at (9,0){Point 9};
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point10) at (9,2) {Point 10};

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point11) at (7,-4){Point 11};
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] (Point12) at (9,-4) {Point 12};

\diagconnect{Point9}{Point10};

\diagconnect{Point11}{Point12}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Old answer (but useful in other cases):**

You can define a `newcommand` with an extra argument (except the \draw options that is optional and the two points that are required) that will be the fraction of the horizontal distance of the points that you want this "break".

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%Command \diagconnect
% #1 is the arguments of \draw command like, red, thick etc
% #2 is the optional argument of the fraction of the horizontal distance for the break according to the horizontal distance of the points
% #3 and #4 are the points to be connected
\newcommand{\diagconnect}[4][]{\draw[#1] let\p1=(#3),\p2=(#4) in (#3)-- ($(#3)+({abs(\x2-\x1)/(\x2-\x1)*abs(\x2-\x1)*#2},0)$)--($(#4)-({abs(\x2-\x1)/(\x2-\x1)*abs(\x2-\x1)*#2},0)$)--(#4);}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Marmot) at (0,1);
\coordinate (Duck) ate (2,0);

\draw (Marmot) -- (Duck);
\draw (Marmot) |- (Duck);

%\draw[red] (Marmot) -- (0.5,1) -- (1.5,0) -- (Duck);
\diagconnect[thick,red]{0.3}{Marmot}{Duck}
\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Marmot) {Marmot Burrow};
\draw (Marmot) circle (0.05);

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Duck) {Duck Pond};
\draw (Duck) circle (0.05);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice idea! Can the angle of the diagonal line be fixed to 45 degree (if the points are further apart the horizontal lines can be longer)?

Comment: Sorry, Didn't notice that you want the degree as an argument... but for smaller horizontal distance than vertical (between this points) it will going back before go diagonal... Are you sure you want something like this? Edit: May be you want the line to start vertical in this case... Working on it

Comment: Please don't apologise, my question was not that clear. For smaller horizontal distances I would like to a connection like the following sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VWIG.png

Answer (score 4):

Based on @koleygr 's answer I changed the code a bit to always draw a 45° connection and adapt to which point is more left/right in the picture (or higher/lower). Unfortunately I couldn't come up with a way to do it horizontally and vertically in an automated fashion, but I provided the two codes for `\hconnect` and `\vconnect`. Maybe someone more experienced with macros and conditional statements can figure out a way to do it even better :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\vconnect}[3][]{
    \draw[#1] let\p1=(#2),\p2=(#3) in (#2)-- ($(#2)+(0,{((\y2-\y1)/abs(\y2-\y1))*(abs(\y2-\y1)-abs(\x2-\x1))*0.5})$)--($(#3)-(0,{((\y2-\y1)/abs(\y2-\y1))*(abs(\y2-\y1)-abs(\x2-\x1))*0.5})$)--(#3);
}
\newcommand{\hconnect}[3][]{
    \draw[#1] let\p1=(#2),\p2=(#3) in (#2)-- ($(#2)+({((\x2-\x1)/abs(\x2-\x1))*(abs(\x2-\x1)-abs(\y2-\y1))*0.5},0)$)--($(#3)-({((\x2-\x1)/abs(\x2-\x1))*(abs(\x2-\x1)-abs(\y2-\y1))*0.5},0)$)--(#3);
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (Marmot) at (0,2);
    \coordinate (Duck) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (Deer) at (2,3);

%   \draw (Marmot) -- (Duck);
%   \draw (Marmot) |- (Duck);

    %\draw[red] (Marmot) -- (0.5,1) -- (1.5,0) -- (Duck);
    \vconnect[thick,red]{Marmot}{Duck}
    \hconnect[thick,red]{Marmot}{Deer}


    \node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Marmot) {Marmot Burrow};
    \draw (Marmot) circle (0.05);

    \node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Deer) {Deer Lake};
    \draw (Deer) circle (0.05);

    \node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Duck) {Duck Pond};
    \draw (Duck) circle (0.05);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you only connect named coordinates (as you do) you can very easily use transformations and normal orthogonal path operations like `-|` and `|-` as well as [`|-|` and `-|-`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\tikzset{
  vertical   slanted by/.style={xslant=tan(-(#1))},
  horizontal slanted by/.style={yslant=tan(#1)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Label/.style={label={[rotate=45, anchor=west]above right:{#1}}},
  dot/.style={circle, inner sep=+.35mm, draw}
]
\coordinate[dot, Label = Marmot Burrow] (Marmot) at (0,1);
\coordinate[dot, Label = Duck Pond]     (Duck)   at (2,0);

\draw (Marmot) -- (Duck);
\draw (Marmot) |- (Duck);

\draw[red] (Marmot) -- (0.5,1) -- (1.5,0) -- (Duck);

\begin{scope}[dashed, thick]
  \draw[blue,  vertical slanted by = 45] (Marmot) -|- (Duck);
  \draw[green, vertical slanted by = 30] (Marmot) |-| (Duck);
\end{scope}
\draw[densely dashed, thick, yellow!50!black, rounded corners,
   horizontal slanted by = 15] (Duck) |- (Marmot);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very fancy! Thanks a lot for your answer!