# Continuous line between nodes of a tikz' matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

In the following `tikz` matrix of nodes, the red line isn't drawn on the `(magic-2-2)` node. How could I make it continuous from `(magic-1-1)` to `(magic-3-3)` nodes, drawn through the (“step” on) node `(magic-2-2)`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary {matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
{
1-1 & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
2-1 & 2-2 & 2-3 \\
3-1 & 3-2 & 3-3 \\
};
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2) -| (magic-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `(magic-2-2)` by `(magic-2-2.center)`?

Comment: That did the trick! Please make your comment an answer in order I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use just the name of a node as a coordinate specification TikZ will automatically choose a point on the node's border that is in the direction of the connecting line viewed from the node's center. If you want to have the line actually go through the node's center, you need to use the `center` anchor.

```
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2.center) -| (magic-3-3);
```

You can use any anchor here since it will stop TikZ from automatically choosing a point on the border. (In this case, both `west` and `east` will lead to the same result.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert={density=150}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]{
  1-1 & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
  2-1 & 2-2 & 2-3 \\
  3-1 & 3-2 & 3-3 \\
};
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2.center) -| (magic-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using @Qrrbrbirlbel's fantastic `ext.paths.ortho` library, you can draw the line in one go without the intermediate stop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
{
1-1 & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
2-1 & 2-2 & 2-3 \\
3-1 & 3-2 & 3-3 \\
};
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |-| (magic-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, indeed. Should be suggested to TikZ maintainers.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Not necessary, I just noticed that this already included in the equally fantastic `\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}` by @ Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: Indeed fantastic library, which the author @Qrrbrbirlbel himself seems to have forgotten :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I don't think the author has forgotten about it, I got a very nice answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685693/36296 only moments after editing this answer here, Qrrbrbirlbel so was probably already busy writing it :)

Comment: Where is the `ext.paths.ortho` library documented?

Comment: `texdoc tikz-ext` (section "9 More Horizontal and Vertical Lines")