# Best way to create a continuous line between nodes in a tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is a follow up to [Denis Bitouzé's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685685/continuous-line-between-nodes-of-a-tikz-matrix-of-nodes)

**Here is his code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary {matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
{
1-1 & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
 &  &  \\
3-1 & 3-2 & 3-3 \\
};
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2.center) -| (magic-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am particularly interesting in the following line of code:

```
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2.center) -| (magic-3-3);
```

The second row in the matrix (mat) was created in order to draw a continuous double rotating line between the node (magic-1-1) and the node (magic-3-3). I do not want to do this since it seems like an unnecessary line of code. I also do not want to use the package that is called
`ext.paths.ortho`. **This is due to the following fact:** I do not like to use too much packages in latex, since the syntax could confuse me.

**I have the following clue on how to create the diagram using only original latex code:**

1. Use the calc package to calculate the right coordinates.

**My question is:**

**What is the best way to create a double rotating continuous line between two nodes in a tikz matrix?**

Comment: Please explain: `I also do not want to use the package that is called ext.paths.ortho. This is due to the following fact: Packages obscure the syntax of latex.`

Comment: It is difficult to learn a large amount of different syntaxes that was created by the package creators.

Comment: To me it is better to learn some basic type of syntax and stick with it. Simple syntax that I will understand. I do not want use too much package derived syntax in my code.

Comment: How is using `ext.paths.ortho` any different than using, say, the matrix library?

Comment: I agree, it is the same. But you should not build package upon package upon package. Somewhere it will become very confusing to the syntax writer.

Comment: You will end up learning just one language in your life.

Comment: If you only want to use "original latex code", why use TikZ? It's a package, not part of the kernel.

Comment: You can see several alternative approaches without the `ext.paths.ortho` library at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478165/how-to-draw-tikz-paths-composed-only-of-horizontal-vertical-and-diagonal-segmen/685693#685693

Comment: Thank you for directing me to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells=true]
{
1-1 & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
&  &  \\
3-1 & 3-2 & 3-3 \\
};
\draw[red,->] (magic-1-1) |- ($(magic-1-1)!0.5!(magic-3-3)$) -| (magic-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix with a red arrow]

*Edit:*

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
{
1-1 & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
2-1 & 2-2 & 2-3 \\
};
\draw[red,->] ([yshift=-4]magic-1-1.center) |- ($(magic-1-1)!0.5!(magic-2-3)$) -| ([yshift=3]magic-2-3.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two line compressed matrix with red arrow]

Comment: Is there a way to remove the second row of the matrix?

Comment: I am not completely sure of what you are asking!? - maybe like in my edit?